# Transactional Operations in InfluxDB

Tags: database, transactions, nosql, influxdb

I have a question regarding transactions operations in InfluxDB. When 2 users have an access to InfluxDB and perform an operation, namely 1 user tries to read data, another user writes data to InfluxDB. Which operation will be executed first, read or write?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB is not a transactional DB so this question does not make sense.

Queries are executed in the order they come in and return data as they see it at the time of querying, further depending on query consistency level if running on a cluster.